# Translog Returns to Scale Variation

Tags: stata, econometrics, panel-data

I estimated the so called translog production function:

$$
y_{it} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 k_{it} + \beta_2 l_{it} + \beta_3 k_{it}^2 + \beta_4 l_{it} \times k_{it} + \beta_5 l_{it}^2 + \epsilon_{it},
$$
where $y$ is the natural logarithm of gross output; $l$ is the log of labour; and $k$ is the log of capital.  I also have a third input - intermediate inputs - but for this discussion I have omitted it for simplicity.

I estimated this equation using clustered robust (to autocorrelation) standard errors (assumes non-constant variance and zero covariance) with fixed time and firm effects.

I want to calculate the variance of the returns to scale.  Returns to scale is defined to be

$$
RTS = e_k + e_l
$$

where

$$ 
e_k = \beta_1 + 2 \beta_3 k_{it} + \beta_4 l_{it}
$$
and
$$ 
e_l = \beta_2 + \beta_4 k_{it} + 2 \beta_5 l_{it}.
$$
That is, returns to scale is the sum of the output elasticities of capital and labour.  The returns to scale for the translog function depends on the level of capital and labour.  Assuming independence between capital, labour, and the estimated coefficients we have
$$
var(e_k) = var(\beta_1) + 4var(\beta_3) var(k_{it}) + var(\beta_4) var(l_{it}).
$$

The variance of the $\beta$'s is outputted in Stata, so this is easily obtainable.  My question boils down to: what should I use for the variance of capital and labour?  I could calculate using all my observations, which would return a constant level of variance.  However, the level of capital a firm has probably depends on capital last year.   Therefore I am not confident that this assumption makes sense.  Could I use the error covariance matrix estimates in the original regression to somehow get variance on capital that is robust to autocorrelation?  Or is there another way to get this?

The independence assumption between capital, labour, and the estimated coefficients is a bit dodgy as well.  What is a good assumption to place here?  Perhaps that the coefficients are independent of capital and labour, but capital and labour are correlated.

Your help is much appreciated.

NB:  This is copied from math.stackexchange.  I have flagged the one on math.stackexchange to be deleted.

Comment: As it explains in the [help](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) please don't cross-post questions like this. If you post a question somewhere and change your mind about where it belongs, flag the original and ask the moderators to move it.

Comment: I've flagged the one on math.stackexchange and deleted my comment about the cross-post.  Thank you.

Comment: If you flag it to move after crossposting, one of the two (this one and the moved one) will then be a duplicate.

Comment: I asked the moderator to delete the one on math.stackexchange and linked this post.  I assume that they will read the comment and delete the one on math.stackexchange.

Comment: Ah, yes, flagging for deletion  is fine. But if you have no answers there you should probably be able to delete it yourself.